# "straight-As", what does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-in-context

> There was a time before heroin took over Jessica Grubb’s life. “She was an incredible achiever, **she made straight-As**, she was smart as a whip, involved in social change,” her father said.

What does **straight-As** mean in the context?

Note:

- I have searched **straight-As** on the QA box, but I didn't find any.
- I was not aware that **As is the same as A's**.
- In my native country, we don't have either **straight-As or A's** classification.

Comment: It means she achieved an "A" grade (usually the highest possible) in all her subjects.

Comment: This is a good question, and it only got closed because we already answered it in a previous question. The closure here is not punitive.

Answer (score 4):

"As" is used as a noun, meaning more than one A. "A" is referring to a grade in school.

"Straight" is the adjective. Together, it means that she received A grades in all of her courses.

The hyphen is incorrect, and probably what is causing the confusion. A hyphen is used when more than one word is used as a single adjective. For example, you could say "She is a straight-A student." But that is not the case in "She made straight As".

Comment: In this case, the hyphen might have been used to so that `As` did not look too much like a capitalized version of  `as`. _Straight A's_ is an easy thing to say, but a difficult thing to write!